# Solr query not equal

Tags: java, solr

is is possible to boost Solr query on "not equal".
ex. i want to boost the docs that have first name not equal to Abdullah.
what is the best way to get this done.
thanks!

Comment: best would be to do two queries and combine them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can simply add to your request:

-firstName:Abdullah

Comment: this would completely remove the docs that have Abdullah, not boost the rest.